# How can I set a chromosome with non repeated alleles using JGAP?

Tags: java, unique, jgap

I'm using JGAP for my code and I want to evaluate chromosomes like this:

```
Evaluation 0: 

 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Evaluation 1: 

 3 5 2 1 4 6 7 8 9
```

Until now, I'm getting chromosomes with repeated alleles, like this:

```
Evaluation 1:

 3 3 5 6 7 8 9 9 1
```

Is there any configuration that I can use in order to get chromosomes with non-repeated alleles?

Comment: This is really way too localized for SO.  You should post this on the JGAP Mailing List (jgap-users@lists.sourceforge.net) instead.

Comment: did you find how to configurate JGap to get chromosomes with non-repeated alleles?

Answer (score 1):

I am supposing that you are talking about generating the initial population of the GA, and what you should to do is to create many random orders of a certain value list.

There are many ways to do so, here's two possibilities:

1. Create an  array of all the possible values, shuffle it, copy it to
   a new
       chromosome, repeat... (you can assign a random real value to each
       possible value, then order the values by the random value).
2. Put all the values in a list, select a random item from the list,
   remove
       it and add it to the chromosome until there are no more values in
       the list, repeat...